# Не работает belongsToMany (Many to Many)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть pivot-таблица `championship_user`:

[image: Table]

Я получаю данные `Championship` пользователя `User` вот так:

```
public function championships()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Championship::class)->withPivot('skill_id', 'role', 'result');
    }
```

В контроллере мне нужно получить все `Championship` пользователя:

```
$championships = Auth::user()->championships();
        $skills = Skill::all();
        dd($championships);
```

Вывод `dd()` такой:

```
#related: Championship {#236 ▼
    #hidden: []
    #guarded: []
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
  }
```

Т.е. он не может найти никакие записи, хотя записи есть:

[image: table]

В чем может быть ошибка? Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем коде была ошибка: `$championships = Auth::user()->championships();`. Там не должно быть `()` в конце. Можно было оставить и так, но тогда нужно добавить `->get()` вот так: `$championships = Auth::user()->championships()->get();`. Т.е. мы создаем запрос, но не выполняем его.

Comment: Все верно, при вызове метода отношения возвращается билдер.